# How to get the row in a NSTableView when rowAtPoint: doesn't reflect the partially visible top row?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

This is the result in a NSTableView where the top visible row is fully visible:

```
======
        rowAtPoint: -> 0
        rowAtPoint: -> 0
------  
        rowAtPoint: -> 1
        rowAtPoint: -> 1
------
```

But I get this kind of result when a NSTableView is in a scroll position where the top visible row is only partially visible:

```
======
        rowAtPoint: -> 0
------  
        rowAtPoint: -> 0   should be 1
        rowAtPoint: -> 1
------  
        rowAtPoint: -> 1   should be 2
        rowAtPoint: -> 2
------
```

Am i misunderstanding the purpose of rowAtPoint: ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-[NSTableView rowAtPoint:]` works in the coordinate system of the table. I guess you're using a point relative to enclosing NSClipView. Use `-[NSView convertPoint:fromView:]` or similar method to get proper coordinate.